# Swift Playground - How to use "thread return -x"

Tags: swift, swift-playground

The following error was invoked when I wrote `case 2841001 ... 393200 :` I figured out my error (having an extra digit in the first number, copy paste error), but I would love to learn how to use "thread return -x", where do I configure that?

```
Playground execution aborted: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).
The process has been left at the point where it was interrupted, use "thread return -x" to return to the state before expression evaluation.
```

Answer (score 6):

I can't find an *official* document about this error message but my explanation is:

This is an LLDB error message, and we shouldn't see this in a Playground, because we don't have access to the debugger in a Playground.

In a regular Xcode project, we could use the debugger to navigate in the debug session, like:

```
(lldb) thread continue
```

But this is not possible in a Playground, so seeing this error in a Playground is, in my opinion, an Xcode bug.

Comment: This thread is 6 years old. Is there a way to handle this now as opposed to 6 years ago?

Answer (score 1):

Just go to Product -> Clear All Issues after fixing your code